# How do I use OR in a elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having an issue with this command. I want to combine both values into one output.

```
curl -s 'server.domain.com:3600/sybok-sdk-'2017.01.13'/_count?q=os:"iPhone%20OS"OR"iOS"' | jq '.count'
```

In this command, its only returning the iPhone%20OS results.

Thank you 
Devon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you have the **OR** condition in between the `+` signs:

```
curl -s 'server.domain.com:3600/sybok-sdk-'2017.01.13'/_count?q=os:"iPhone%20OS"+OR+"iOS"' | jq '.count'
```

**OR**

```
curl -s 'server.domain.com:3600/sybok-sdk-'2017.01.13'/_count?q=os:"iPhone%20OS"OR"iOS"' | jq '.count'
```

You might want to have a look at [this](http://logz.io/blog/elasticsearch-queries/), hope it helps!

Comment: The second one worked with no spaces, "iPhone%20OS"OR"iOS".. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names) doc you have to do next:

```
curl -s 'server.domain.com:3600/sybok-sdk-'2017.01.13'/_count?q=os:("iPhone%20OS" "iOS")' | jq '.count'
```

Comment: No results on this one.. If I have one in there, it will provide results, but once I add the second one as you posted, I get no results.